# Javascript with php query

Tags: javascript, php

When I try to foreach, only first ID's photo comes on slider. After that every other user's ID is missing, doesn't show on slider.

Only one slider is visible.

How can I fix that?

```
<?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) {  ?>
      <div class="quick-view-modal modalopen" id="<?php echo $query_result["ID"] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ad-modal">
            <button class="close close-btn popup-cls" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"> <i class="fa-times fa"></i> </button>
            <div class="modal-content single-product">
               <div class="diblock">
                  <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                     <div id="single-slider" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture1"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture2"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture3"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture4"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture5"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture6"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture7"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture8"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture9"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture10"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture11"] ?>" /></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture12"] ?>" /></li>

                        </ul>
                     </div>

                     <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture1"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture2"] ?>"> </li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture3"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture4"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture5"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture6"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture7"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture8"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture9"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture10"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture11"] ?>"></li>
                           <li><img alt="" src="<?php echo $query_result["picture12"] ?>"></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>

<script src="js/nouislider.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/carousel.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/slide.js"></script>
```

Photos of first ID, visible slider: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjrfY.png
Photos of second ID, no slider visible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtNFX.png

Answer (score -1):

I think you can used only one id="single-slider" your javascript code other than can you put your js code, so I can give you a proper solution.
thanks

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 65119.
I can't.